File upload by public is disabled
After pinning the location from the map in the Xcode simulator, I get the error “File upload by public is disabled” when I want to save it. how do I solve it, can you help? enter image description here
I did various operations on Parse but it did not work.

Welcome to SO. In general the best questions include the code you're having difficulty with along with the troubleshooting and expected result. Is this a code specific question? Please take a moment and review How to ask a question and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
